Query attribute from another aggregate
I am build a transaction management application, i have 2 aggregate customer and transaction like this.
public class Transaction extends BaseAggregate<TransactionId> {
    private UserId customerId;
    private UserId employeeId;
    private PrinterId printerId;
    private String name;
    private PrintTransactionStatus status;
    private List<PaperQuantity> transactionPaperQuantities = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<TransactionDocument> transactionDocuments = new ArrayList<>();

    public Transaction(UserId customerId, PrinterId printerId, String name) {
        super(new TransactionId(UUID.randomUUID()));
        this.name = name;
        this.status = PrintTransactionStatus.PENDING;
        this.customerId = customerId;
        this.printerId = printerId;
        // init paper quantities
        PaperQuantity paperQuantityA3 = new PaperQuantity(PaperType.A3, 0);
        PaperQuantity paperQuantityA4 = new PaperQuantity(PaperType.A4, 0);
        PaperQuantity paperQuantityA5 = new PaperQuantity(PaperType.A5, 0);
        for (TransactionDocument transactionDocument : transactionDocuments) {
            PaperQuantity totalPaper = transactionDocument.getTotalPaper();
            switch (totalPaper.getType()) {
                case PaperType.A3:
                    paperQuantityA3 = paperQuantityA3.add(totalPaper);
                    break;
                case PaperType.A4:
                    paperQuantityA4 = paperQuantityA4.add(totalPaper);
                    break;
                case PaperType.A5:
                    paperQuantityA5 = paperQuantityA5.add(totalPaper);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        this.transactionPaperQuantities.add(paperQuantityA3);
        this.transactionPaperQuantities.add(paperQuantityA4);
        this.transactionPaperQuantities.add(paperQuantityA5);
    }

    public void addDocument(DocumentId documentId, DocumentDetail detail) {
        if (this.transactionDocuments.size() == 5) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Exceed document limit");
        }
        this.transactionDocuments.add(new TransactionDocument(documentId, detail));
    }

    public void removeDocuuent(TransactionDocument document) {
        boolean isDeleted = this.transactionDocuments.remove(document);
        if (!isDeleted) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Document not exist");
        }
    }
}

And the customer
public class Customer extends BaseAggregate<UserId> {
        private CustomerId customerId;
        @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
        private List<PaperQuantity> paperQuantities;
        private List<TransactionId> transactionIds = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<DocumentId> documentIds = new ArrayList<>();

        public Customer(UserId userId, CustomerId customerId) {
                super(userId);
                this.customerId = customerId;
                this.paperQuantities = List.of(
                                new PaperQuantity(PaperType.A3, 0),
                                new PaperQuantity(PaperType.A4, 0),
                                new PaperQuantity(PaperType.A5, 0));
        }

        public void addPaper(PaperQuantity quanity) {
                PaperQuantity currentPaperQuantity = this.paperQuantities.stream()
                                .filter((paperQuantity) -> paperQuantity.getType().equals(quanity.getType()))
                                .findFirst()
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong paper type"));
                PaperQuantity newPaperQuantity = new PaperQuantity(quanity.getType(),
                                currentPaperQuantity.getQuantity() + quanity.getQuantity());
                this.paperQuantities.remove(currentPaperQuantity);
                this.paperQuantities.add(newPaperQuantity);
        }

        public void subtractPaper(PaperQuantity quantity) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                PaperQuantity currentPaperQuantity = this.paperQuantities.stream()
                                .filter((paperQuantity) -> paperQuantity.getType().equals(quantity.getType()))
                                .findFirst()
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong paper type"));
                if (currentPaperQuantity.getQuantity() < quantity.getQuantity()) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Don't enoungh paper");
                }
                PaperQuantity newPaperQuantity = new PaperQuantity(quantity.getType(),
                                currentPaperQuantity.getQuantity() - quantity.getQuantity());
                this.paperQuantities.remove(currentPaperQuantity);
                this.paperQuantities.add(newPaperQuantity);
        }

        public void addTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
                if (transactionIds.contains(transaction.getId())) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Transaction already exists.");
                }
                transactionIds.add(transaction.getId());
        }

        public void removeTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
                boolean removed = transactionIds.remove(transaction.getId());
                if (!removed) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Transaction does not exist.");
                }
        }

        public void addDocument(Document document) {
                if (documentIds.contains(document.getId())) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Document already exists.");
                }
                documentIds.add(document.getId());
        }

        public void removeDocument(Document document) {
                boolean removed = documentIds.remove(document.getId());
                if (!removed) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Document does not exist.");
                }
        }
}

I want to query list of transaction with customer name for the UI. What should i design in domain layer by design repository to return list of transaction result with customer name.
